# How does a client request work with AWS regions?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I'm trying to understand how AWS regions work.

Walk me through a web browser GET request on a web application hosted across AWS regions and availability zones.

How does a load balancer and individual instances fit into this request?

How does a request decide which region to use?

Which IP address should be your A record Entry for a domain, if the web application is hosted across Regions on AWS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TLDR; in AWS it's much easier to have an application span an availability zone (aka independent data centers built close together) than regions. AWS provides good support for this.

**The longer story**

AWS Regions are almost completely separate. There's no really easy automatic way to span regions in a single application, other than running separate copies of that application in each region. You typically use availability zones, which are a number of separate data centers located closely together but with independent infrastructure, usually <1ms apart. AWS will never move data outside a region without you explicitly telling it to, this is necessary for enterprises who may not want their data to leave a specific country. A region typically has three AZs, though in some areas AWS actually has many more data centers, I suspect people are assigned to them to spread the load.

A load balancer (ELB) easily distributes traffic between different AZs inside a region, so if one data center fails the others in the region can easily take over, including creating more resources if required and you've configured it to (auto scaling). AZs share resources much more easily as they're so close together, network latency wise. The Relational Database Service can keep synchronous databases in different AZs within a region, but not between regions, though you can have asynchronous replicas in another region.

If you want to load balance across regions the primary way is to use Route 53, AWS's DNS offering. This can load balance based on failover, geographic location, simple round robin, and probably others. The problem is if you need a single central database, that would need to be in one region. You can synchronise but it introduces risk and latency. If you can store your data in each region and the data is read only or write rarely this is much easier, but you'd have to work out database synchronisation yourself. Stateless applications or applications with rarely changing data would be particularly easy to spread across a region.

You can use the Cloudfront CDN to cache data at any of AWS's many edge locations, but the source of this will be a single region. It's typically done for performance.

Regions would used more in a DR scenario than for load balancing. You can reasonably easily copy your resources (data, virtual machine images) between regions and script loading creation of any other resources required, like queues, database, etc. If a whole region goes down, which is rare but can happen, DNS health checks will direct your users to another region.

You may be able to set up something like a VPN that lets your application span regions, but there are issues with consistency of databases and such, and probably few advantages. AZs are sufficiently robust in most cases. If you need [very high availability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_availability) you can architect what you need, but be prepared to pay for very smart people and sufficient resources.

You asked to be walked through how an application will load balance across AZ. Instead I suggest you read the extensive documentation AWS provides, including [FAQs and product documentation](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/).

Comment: sorry this took a few days to accept, this is a great description! @tim

Answer (score -1):

Can you make a better definition of "client"? Do you mean a client of an application or the Amazon command line client?

To answer what I think you're asking:

An ELB will load balance your requests through instances in different AZ's within a region.
eg eu-west-1a and eu-west-1b. both zones within the eu-west-1 (Ireland) region.

I think if you want to load balance across regions, you would need some DNS magic.

There isn't much to walk through, request comes in, hits an EIP, which is connected to your ELB. The ELB passes that request to any instances you told it to use.

Comment: A client being a web browser, hitting a domain such as amazon.com, I imagine amazon.com is hosted across many regions. 

How does my browser differentiate between regions? How does it decide to connect to N California rather than London?

If I have an application, such as Amazon.com - which IP address would I use as my DNS A Record entry? Wouldn't this alway map to a specific region.

The whole region concept has me confused.

Comment: ELB doesn't have an EIP, it has a CNAME. DNS Magic = Route 53.